# How can I set up an effective unit testing and scenario testing framework for an Express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, coffeescript

I'm setting up an `Express` / `AngularJS` project. Express will serve the static assets for AngularJS and act as an API server. I want to unit test my express controllers and endpoints.

I may have some scenarios as well that need to be tested (like first create a user, then login, etc). I also want code coverage. Oh, did I mention that it's all in `CoffeeScript` as well?

I'm using `karma` and `jasmine` for my Angular tests. I'd like to stick to similar frameworks for the node.js layer.

Any suggestions on getting started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[supertest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest) is great for this. You should be able to use it with jasmine or mocha easily. [supertest-session](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest-session) can help with mocking out a logged-in user.

Have a look at some of these mocha + supertest tests if you need an example: https://github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com/tree/master/test/application

Comment: How do I use this to test controllers?

Comment: You send mock HTTP requests to your app and set expectations about the responses. It tests your full stack including routes and controllers. Try something. Post some code.

Comment: Link to examples added.

Comment: It looks like Supertest is actually starting the server and sending requests.  Is it really creating mocks? I can't find any reference to this in the documentation.  This looks like Integration testing rather than unit tests.

Comment: Don't want to debate the semantics of unit testing. If you mock out your database then send a superagent request which is real, I call that unit testing. The OP is asking about scenarios which are much larger in scope than your typical unit test. He's also asking about code coverage, which usually means end-to-end.